# Combining 'plain' jQuery Validate with Unobtrusive

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

How can I add additional jQuery Validate rules to my MVC3 form when the page includes jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js?

I have some 'manually' created  elements at the bottom of the form that I would like to add some simple client-side validation to, but with the unobtrusive script loaded, the following does not work, i.e. the filed does not validate.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
    "broadcast-blockSize": {
        required: true,
        number: true
    }
}
```

Comment: See the following post [Imran Baloch's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/07/13/overriding-unobtrusive-client-side-validation-settings-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have little experience with client-side code, I was helping my colleague looking up some pointers.  I found many links, but they did not work for him (maybe because most were MVC3, and he is using MVC4).
However, he figured out a way to do it in MVC3, so I'll just post that code.  I don't know if it will work for MVC3 (requested by OP), but I hope it will help someone.

While using unobtrusive validation for most fields my colleague adds a rule using code similar to the code underneath at the bottom of an EditorTemplate (for a Partialview):

```
...
</fieldset>
@this.ScriptBlock(
    @<script>
         $(function() {
             ...
             $("#@Html.IdFor(m=>m.Referral)").rules("add", {
                 required: "#requires-referral-ja:checked",
                 messages: { required: "The field Referral is required." }
             });
        });
        ...
    </script>
)
```